# Regex - Capture multiple multiline text blocks with only a starting pattern

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a very large text file with several entries like this:

```
    -------------------------------------
    
       LOTS OF
        MULTILINE
       TEXT
    
    *************************************
              MORE
       MULTILINE
         TEXT
    
    *************************************
    
       EVEN-MORE-TEXT-SOMETIMES-WITH-DASHES
    
    *************************************

    -------------------------------------

       2ND LOT OF
        MULTILINE
       TEXT
    
    *************************************
      MORE
       MULTILINE
         TEXT FOR 2ND LOT
    
    *************************************
    
       EVEN-MORE-TEXT-FOR-2ND

    *************************************
```

Note that these are only two entries, I don't care about the asterisks, but the text that follows the dashed line.

I want to get a capture group with all the text in each entry so that I can analyze it later line by line.

I can capture the first entry with an expression like this:

`/-{37}\s*([\s\S]+)-{37}/gm`

But I'm having trouble running the capture group several times because I don't have a clear terminator for the groups (since the *{37} appears several times)

Here's a regex 101 example:

https://regex101.com/r/XZQ5h6/1

How can I capture the text after the dashed line but before the next dashed line or the end of the file?

Edit:
So to make my question clearer, the capture group I would expect for the first entry would be.

```
   LOTS OF
    MULTILINE
   TEXT

*************************************
          MORE
   MULTILINE
     TEXT

*************************************

   EVEN-MORE-TEXT-SOMETIMES-WITH-DASHES

*************************************
```

I also happen to have some dashes in the text, so I have edited the example. Ideally, I want an array of capture groups with just the content in the entries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```sh
-{37}\R+((?:.+\R)+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZQ5h6/3)

**RegEx Detail;**

- `-{37}`: Match hyphen of 37 in length
- `\R+`: Match 1+ of line breaks
- `(`: Start capture group

  - `(?:.+\R)+`: Match a line of 1+ character followed by a line break. Repeat this group 1+ times to match multiple of these lines
- `)`: End capture group

Comment: @Dennis: Did this work out for you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @anubhava. I think it was not clear in my question but I need to capture everything until the next -{37}. So in my example, the capture group would need to be everything until the asterisks.

I'll edit my question, but I'm grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match both entries:

```
/-{37}[^-]+/gm
```

Try it out in regex101.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the 2 parts in the example data in a capture group:

```
^-{37}\s*^((?:(?!--).*(?:\r?\n|$))+)
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `-{37}` Match 37 times a `-` char
- `\s*^` Match optional whitespace chars, and assert start of string (note to use the multiline flag due to the anchors)
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!--)` Negative lookahead, assert not `--` at the start of the string (or make it more specific like `(?!-{37}\r?\n)`)
    - `.*(?:\r?\n|$)` Match the whole line followed by a newline or assert the end of the string
  - `)+` Close non capture group 1+ times
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uvGj45/1)

Or a bit shorter, but then it would include the leading whitespace chars in the match:

```
^-{37}((?:\r?\n(?!--).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/snjQZO/1)